# Transfer Solana using Solders for Python

Tags: solana-program, transfer, solana.py

I am still new to this and have been trying to figure this out for some time now so any help you can offer would really be greatly appreciated.

I see quite a bit of literature and tutorials on how to transfer Sol using Solana.py (which no longer works) and I have been combing through the Solders docs trying to put it together but can't get it.

Does anyone have an idea of how a function to transfer Sol from one wallet to another using Solders would look?

https://kevinheavey.github.io/solders/api_reference/transaction.html

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from the solana-py docs (lightly edited):

```
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
from solana.transaction import Transaction
sender = Keypair.from_bytes(b"") # replace with a real keypair
receiver = Keypair().pubkey()
transfer_ix = transfer(TransferParams(from_pubkey=sender.pubkey(), to_pubkey=receiver.pubkey(), lamports=1_000_000))
txn = Transaction().add(transfer_ix)
solana_client = Client("http://localhost:8899") # replace with a real RPC
solana_client.send_transaction(txn, sender)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After playing with this for awhile I finally got it to work. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I will be changing this message as I can not delete accepted answers

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is VSCode giving you trouble with the Solders types or something?

Comment: not vscode, mypy

Comment: Yeah, I get "TypeError: Transaction.__new__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'from_keypairs', 'message', and 'recent_blockhash'" when I run your code.

Answer (score -1):

The solders code seems a bit raw currently. There seems to be instructions only for `SystemProgram`.
I'm not sure what are the other design ideas being but Solana clients For transferring SOL you need to create an instruction of the `SystemProgram`, place it to a transaction, sign it (if needed, signature of the wallet could be added automatically, not sure though how it is here) and send it to network.

Based on the documentation I tried like this

```
import json
import requests
import json
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.message import Message # type: ignore
from solders.transaction import Transaction # type: ignore
from solders.system_program import transfer, TransferParams
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey as PublicKey # type: ignore
from solders.keypair import Keypair # type: ignore
from solders.hash import Hash # type: ignore
from solders.commitment_config import CommitmentLevel # type: ignore
from solders.rpc.config import RpcSendTransactionConfig # type: ignore
from solders.rpc.requests import SendLegacyTransaction # type: ignore

SOL_TO_LAMPORTS = 1000000000

to = PublicKey.from_string("7xUpLb33Bp3yGKVsARWzAQiYanXL1ujx3136qoJCLWXN")
instruction = transfer(
    TransferParams(
        from_pubkey = loaded_keypair.pubkey(),
        to_pubkey = PublicKey.from_string("<some_pubkey_base58"),
        lamports = SOL_TO_LAMPORTS
    )
)

# solana api to get recent blockhash
solana_client = Client(args.rpc, timeout=30)
recent_blockhash = solana_client.get_recent_blockhash()
blockhash = Hash.from_string(recent_blockhash['result']['value']['blockhash'])

message = Message([instruction], loaded_keypair.pubkey())
tx = Transaction([loaded_keypair], message, blockhash)

commitment = CommitmentLevel.Confirmed
config = RpcSendTransactionConfig(preflight_commitment=commitment)
req = SendLegacyTransaction(tx, config)
as_json = req.to_json()  # as_json returns a string not a json

print('sending', SOL_TO_LAMPORTS, 'to', to)
res = requests.post(args.rpc, json=json.loads(as_json))
print(res.json())
```

For sending there seems not being a direct integration to `solana.rpc.api.Client` and the transaction can be get as a JSON to be sent via HTTP request.

Comment: Ok, thanks @kevinh for the clarification of the usage.